# Zend framework SQL select query construction (ORDER BY)

Tags: zend-framework, mysql, sql-order-by, clause

I have a database with VARCHAR column `url`. I would like to fetch rows so that the ones that have any `url` value have priority over other rows, but are ordered by `date` row (descending), so `ORDER BY 'url' DESC, 'date' DESC` wouldn't work as it would order them alphabetically first. Basically, it would look something like this:

Table:

```
ID   |    Url    | Date
1    | http://...| 1001
2    |           | 1002
3    |           | 1003
4    | http://...| 1005
5    | http://...| 1004
```

Sorted:

```
ID   |    Url    | Date
4    | http://...| 1005
5    | http://...| 1004
1    | http://...| 1001
3    |           | 1003
2    |           | 1002
```

What would be the proper zend framework way (or at least SQL query) to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SQL, you could so something like...

It gets kind of ugly if you allow null values on the url field as well.

```
SELECT * , IF(LENGTH(url) = 0 OR url IS NULL, 1, 0) AS nourl 
FROM url ORDER BY nourl ASC
```

This basically checks to see if the url length is greater than zero or is null. If they are, they are at the bottom of the sort.

Comment: Perhaps using the CASE statement is better because it is in the ANSI standard. As well, you can put the case/if statement directly in the ORDER by clause - so you don't have to select a dummy column

Comment: I can get behind that. I guess I always thought of those as being more for stored procedures. I personally would still probably leave it in the column list however. It might be nice down the line to be able to do logic on the nourl column.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `order by field('field_name', value) desc` in the select statement.